# Unresolved function or method then() AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json

I am using below code and getting the error: `Unresolved function or method then()`.
 I don't know what is wrong in here. I am using WebStorm 11. I have included angular-route.min.js,angular-resource.min.js,angular.min.js,angular-cookies.js,bootstrap.min.js and jquery.min.js in my script .

This is my controller and below :

```
RecordApp.controller('MyController',
['$scope','recordaccess',function($http,$route,$scope,recordaccess,                   
$location,$rootScope,$cookieStore) {
recordaccess.then(function(data) {------>Here I am getting error.
.
.
.
});
```

And this I am using to fetch data from JSON:

```
RecordApp.factory('recordaccess', ['$http', function($http) {
return $http.get('record1.json')
.then(function successCallback(response) {------>Here I am getting error.
return response.data;
},
function errorCallback(response) {
alert("Error occurred. Status: " + 
response.status + " - " + response.statusText);
});
}]);
```

Comment: The injection list doesn't fit with the function arguments. Try something as ['$http', '$route', '$scope','recordaccess','$location','$rootscope','$cookieStore',function($http,$route,$scope,recordaccess,                   
$location,$rootScope,$cookieStore)

Comment: @atao I tried using this but no luck .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You factory-declaration is wrong, example:

```
module.factory('MyFactory', function() {

    var factory = {}; 

    factory.method1 = function() {
            //..
        }

    factory.method2 = function() {
            //..
        }

    return factory;
});
```

Then you can use it like:

```
MyFactory.method1().then(function(data){...});
```